# Failure to change value in a textfield list with TextEditingController

Tags: android, listview, flutter, sqflite

I have a textfield list with values
- when I change the value of a textfield
- and when I try to reduce the keyboard (to finish the modification to move to another field), my modification is not taken into account, it gives back the old value, it is as if it reloaded the list again , what should I do to maintain my change,
thank you.

[image: Flutter : failure to change value in a textfield list]

Comment: Hello, Able. Please edit your question and add some code of what your doing, specially the TextField and the usage of the controller.

Comment: the solution I was proposed on https://gist.github.com/buthmathearo/55d806d89cf09abc2fc75b18c26d6a7f

Comment: the solution is that i had to use the list in initState, then stop in has,

Comment: but my big problem in the original code, I have to use a list that comes from another method, so I will not be able to apply the proposed solution.,